# How to send large data (<100mb) as response from cloud function to client?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In cloud function I have a code which connect with bigquery using service account, execute the query and send the response to local client machine. But the response data is very large (<300mb) which is 'csv' data.

currently, I am getting only 10MB data that is 14k rows in my response 'csv' file.

Comment: Edit your question and include your code and error messages.

Comment: I don't have any error messages, but the problem I am facing is not receiving full data as response.

Comment: You can send you response in multipart format, or put the file on Cloud Storage and send a redirect response to the signed URL of your file on Cloud Storage